# Include third party DLL Amyuni PDFCreator in my Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, dll

I download [this
third party SDK](https://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatoractivex/download/) I want to use in my C++ Qt project. If you download the zip you get some documentation, samples and there is a SDK folder with 3 DLLs.

I followed these steps from [the documentation](https://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_ACTIVE_X/Overview/Inserting_the_PDF_Creator_control_into_a_project/In_a_Cplus_environment/MFC_Console_Application.htm):

1. I registered **PDFCreactiveX.dll** via **regsvr32** - OK
2. I import the file like this: `#import "Amyuni/SDK/Win32/PDFCreactiveX.dll"` to my **stdafx.h** because according to documentation I want to use it in multiple files.

But when I include **stdafx.h** in my **global.h** header (which is my header where I include my all third party SDKs and instantiate them) it doesn't work for me like the documentation said.

```
IPDFCreactiveXPtr gPDFptr;
```

The Compiler does not know what `IPDFCreactiveXPtr` is and I also need make it a global variable to work with the same instance in other .cpp files.